# Zeta zero sum & reciprocals of prime powers

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Below is a plot of $$\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{75}2\Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_n\log\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$

[image]

where $\rho_n$ is the $n$th zeta zero, with grid lines at primes and prime powers & $y=\pm\frac{1}{2}.$

My question: does $$\dfrac{1}{x+\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2\Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_n\log\left(x\right)\right)\right)-\dfrac{1}{x-\epsilon}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2\Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_n\log\left(x\right)\right)\right)=1$$

for all $x=\frac{1}{\text{prime}}$?

Comment: What is $\Re$ and what is $\rm Ei$?

Comment: @Klangen $\Re(y)$ is the real part of $y$ and $Ei(y)$ is the exponential integral function related to the logarithmic integral function via the relationship $li(y)=Ei(log(y))$ which is valid for $y>0$.

Comment: @Klangen The formula in this question is related to Riemann's prime-power counting function $\Pi(x)=\sum_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}$ (which takes a step of $\frac{1}{n}$ at each prime-power $x=p^n$) and Riemann's corresponding explicit formula $\Pi_o(x)=li(x)-\sum_\rho Ei(\rho\log x)-\log(2)-\sum_n Ei(-2\,n\log x)$ which is vald for $x>1$. The non-trivial zeta zeros come in pairs and the OP's question takes advantage of the fact that $Ei(\rho_k\log x)+Ei(\rho_{-k}\log x)=2\,\Re(Ei(\rho_k\log x))$.

Comment: @martin $\underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{x+\epsilon}-\frac{1}{x-\epsilon }\right)f(x)=0$. Did you mean $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\,\Re\left(\text{Ei}\left(\rho_n\log(x+\epsilon)\right)\right)}{x+\epsilon}-\frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2\,\Re\left(\text{Ei}\left(\rho_n\log(x-\epsilon)\right)\right)}{x-\epsilon}=1$?